# How to excute java file from remote desktop(mstsc)

Tags: cmd, mstsc

I logged into my remote desktop location from cmd by mstsc command. Made some changes in java file and saved it. But I am not sure how can I execute the java file from remote location. Can someone help me out.

Thanks and Regards,
Sm.Aslam.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean an uncompiled `.java` file. In that case, it is as easy as typing the following in Command Prompt:

```
javac file.java
```

Note that this requires Java to be installed on the remote computer. If this is not the case, you will have to install it.

Regards,
Gabe